# MUI Autocomplete: always show all options / do not filter options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to disable any filtering in the MUI Autocomplete component. I only need the text field popper to show all available options.

Results are fetched from a server-side search engine. These results or "hits" already contain a filtered view of available options.

The MUI docs reference a [custom filter](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#custom-filter) but I am unsure how to configure it to match all options.

How do I disable any filtering in Autocomplete?

```
<Autocomplete
  getOptionLabel={(option) => (option.projectName ? option.projectName : option)}
  options={searchFunctions.convertHitsToOptions(searchQuery.data)}
  filterOptions={ ??? }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning options without any changes in the filterOptions function will result in no filtering:

```
filterOptions={(options) => options}
```

[MUI API docs on filter options](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-filterOptions)